# Прозрачные области .png (background-image) перекрывают задний фон

Tags: css, background

Делаю кнопку в виде картинки через background-image из .png, с прозрачными областями.

Эти прозрачные области перекрывают задний фон блока:
[image: background button]

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.btn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px 1px rgba(63, 84, 112, 0.1);
}

.btn-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
}

.reduct-btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  /* Не помогает ни transparent ни white */
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("./img/iconNo.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="btn-wrap">
    <button class="btn reduct-btn"></button>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что область c квадратами реально прозрачная? :D

Comment: У вас картинка наверняка вот [такого](https://img1.pnghut.com/16/3/25/rBAMasgceD/ban-symbol-area-black-and-white-font-awesome.jpg) вида.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, ваша картинка не имеет прозрачного фона. У нее есть имитация прозрачного фона. Вам достаточно найти фотографии, благодаря расширенному поиску в гугле(или на спец.сайтах),с действительно прозрачным фоном